# Blow-ups of $\mathbb{P}^{n-3}$ and $(\mathbb{P}^1)^{n-3}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, birational-geometry, divisors, blow-ups

Let us consider the points 
$$p_1=[1:0:...:0],p_2 = [0:1:...:0],...,p_{n-2} =[0:...:0:1],\\ 
p_{n-1}=[1:1:...:1]\in\mathbb{P}^{n-3}$$ 
and the blow-up $X = Bl_{p_1,...,p_{n-1}}\mathbb{P}^{n-3}$.

Furthermore, consider 
$$p_1 = ([0:1],...,[0:1]), p_2 = ([1:0],...,[1:0]), p_3=([1:1],...,[1:1])\in (\mathbb{P}^1)^{n-3}$$
and the blow-up $Y = Bl_{p_1,p_2,p_3}(\mathbb{P}^1)^{n-3}$. Note that for the Picard numbers we have 
$$\rho(X) = n = \rho(Y).$$
Does there exist a small $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial transformation $f:X\dashrightarrow Y$?

Comment: What does it mean for a rational map to be $\mathbb Q$-factorial?

Comment: A small $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial modification of X is a birational map $g:X\dashrightarrow Y$, where $Y$ is a normal, projective, and $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial, and $g$ is an isomorphism in codimension $1$.

Comment: I assume you are asking whether $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic away from a codim $\geq 2$ subset?

Comment: Exactly. That's it!

Comment: Maybe you know this, but maybe it can be helpful. (It's not an answer.) The space $\overline M_{0,n}$ can be obtained from $\mathbf P^{n-3}$ by a sequence of blow ups, where the first step is blowing up at $(n-1)$ points in general position. This is in Kapranov, "Chow quotients of Grassmannian I". It can also be obtained by iterated blowing up of $(\mathbf P^1)^{n-3}$ where the first step is blowing up at the three points you picked.  This is in Tavakol, "The Chow ring of the moduli space of curves of genus zero".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an explicit way to construct a small modification.

Consider the points $p_1,...,p_{n-3}$. We have $n-3$ codimension two linear subspaces $H_{i_1,...,i_{n-4}}^{n-5} = \left\langle p_{i_1},...,p_{i_{n-4}}\right\rangle$. For any choice of $i_1,...,i_{n-4}$ we define $\{j_1,j_2\} = \{0,...,n-3\}\setminus\{i_1-1,...,i_{n-4}-1\}$. Then, the projection from $H_{i_1,...,i_{n-4}}^{n-5}$ is the rational map
$$ 
\begin{array}{lccc}
  \pi_{i_1,...,i_{n-4}}: & \mathbb{P}^{n-3} & \dashrightarrow & \mathbb{P}^1 \\ 
   & \left[x_0:...:x_{n-3}\right] & \mapsto & [x_{j_1}:x_{j_2}]
\end{array}   
$$
We get a rational map 
$$ 
\begin{array}{lccc}
  g: & \mathbb{P}^{n-3} & \dashrightarrow & (\mathbb{P}^1)^{n-3} \\ 
   & x=\left[x_0:...:x_{n-3}\right] & \mapsto & (\pi_{1,...,n-4}(x),...,\pi_{2,...,n-3}(x))
\end{array}   
$$
Note that the hyperplane $W = \left\langle p_1,...,p_{n-3}\right\rangle = \{x_{n-3}=0\}$ is mapped by $g$ to the point $q_1=([1:0],...,[1:0])\in (\mathbb{P}^1)^{n-3}$. Furthermore, this is the only divisor contracted by $g$. Therefore, blowing-up $q_1\in (\mathbb{P}^1)^{n-3}$ we get a small transformation $g_1:X_{n-3}^{n-3} = Bl_{p_1,...,p_{n-3}}\mathbb{P}^{n-3}\dashrightarrow Y_1^{n-3} = Bl_{q_1}(\mathbb{P}^1)^{n-3}$ mapping $\widetilde{W}$ (the strict transform of $W$) to the exceptional divisor $E_{q_1}$, while the exceptional divisors $E_{p_1},...,E_{p_{n-3}}$ are mapped to the strict transforms of the $n-3$ divisors in $(\mathbb{P}^1)^{n-3}$ obtained by fixing one the factors.

Furthermore, $g([0:...:0:1]) = ([0:1],...,[0:1])$ and $g([1:...:1]) = ([1:1],...,[1:1])$. Let $\mathcal{U}\subset X_{n-3}^{n-3}$ and $\mathcal{V}\subset Y_1^{n-3}$ be the two open subsets on which $g_1$ is an isomorphism. Now, by applying the universal property of the blow-up we get that $g_{1|\mathcal{U}}$ lifts to an isomorphism $f:Bl_{p_{n-2},p_{n-1}}\mathcal{U}\rightarrow Bl_{q_2,q_3}\mathcal{V}$. Since $g_1$ is an isomorphism in codimension one we conclude that $f$ induces a small transformation $f:X = Bl_{p_1,...,p_{n-1}}\mathbb{P}^n\dashrightarrow Y=Bl_{q_1,q_2,q_3}(\mathbb{P}^1)^{n-3}$ mapping $E_{p_{n-2}}$ to $E_{q_2}$, and $E_{p_{n-3}}$ to $E_{q_3}$.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is yes. Let us forget about the points $p_{n-1} = [1:\ldots:1] \in \mathbb{P}^{n-3}$ and $p_3 = ([1:1], \ldots, [1:1])\in (\mathbb{P}^1)^{n-3}$ for the moment. Now the two blow-ups are toric varieties, with an action of the torus $T=\mathbb{G}_m^{n-3}$. To show that they are isomorphic in codimension $1$, we need to show that the corresponding fans have the same rays. Now $\mathbb{P}^{n-3}$ has rays $e_1, \ldots, e_{n-3}$ and $-e_1-\ldots-e_{n-3}$ where the $e_i$ are standard basis vectors of the co-character lattice $N$ of $T$. Blowing up the $T$-invariant points adds the rays $-e_1, \ldots, -e_{n-3}$ and $e_1 + \ldots + e_{n-3}$. For $(\mathbb{P}^1)^{n-3}$, we start with the rays $\pm e_1, \ldots, \pm e_{n-3}$ and the blow-up at $p_1$ and $p_2$ introduces the rays $\pm (e_1 + \ldots e_{n-3})$. We conclude that if we forget to blow upthe two non-$T$-invariant points, the two varieties we get are isomorphic in codimension $1$.

To get what we want, we observe that both varieties are toric varieties, and on both sides we blow up a point in the dense orbit. We can use $T$ to move that point on both sides to the locus where the birational isomorphism is defined.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, to make your argument work don't we need the birational isomorphism $g$ between the two toric varieties to be toric? If so, then we can move $g([1:...:1])$ to $([1:1],...,[1:1])$ via $T$ and then conclude. How do we know that $g$ is toric? Thanks.

Comment: It is indeed toric - it's the identity on the torus, and the analysis of fans is used to show that it extends to the open orbits of the boundary divisors.

Comment: I like the trick with moving "extra" points, but it would still be nice to have a purely geometric construction.